# Trying to install wxWidgets

Tags: c++, mingw, wxwidgets, codeblocks

I've been trying to install wxWidgets into Code::Blocks and have been having issues. I'm following a guide off of the wiki; it says to put `mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc BUILD=release SHARED=1 MONOLITHIC=1 UNICODE=1 CXXFLAGS=-fno-keep-inline-dllexport` into the command line.

When I do, this error is returned: "'mingw32-make' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file". I have created a path entry for "c:/MinGW/bin", so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to download the prebuilt binaries.

They are [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxwindows/files/3.0.1/binaries/).

For developing applications with wxWidgets you need to download the compiler-independent wxWidgets-3.0.1_Headers.7z file (found in the parent directory) and wxMSW-3.0.1_gccXXX_Dev.7z files depending on your compiler, its version and the target architecture (x86 if not specified or x64).

Unpack both files into the same directory so that "include" and "lib" directories are at the same level after unpacking. You should be able to compile and link applications using wxWidgets in both debug and release modes but the debug symbols are provided only for debug libraries in this archive, see below for the release build debug symbols.

To compile, you will have to add the include folder to your compiler search directories.  Use a global variable setting.  To link, add the lib folder to your linker setting, agains using a global variable.

[image]

Comment: Could use some more info on this. After I do this, should I be able to compile a wxWidgets application through codeblocks without doing anything else? And which one do I want on that link?

Comment: Okay, I have lib and include unpacked into a file, what now?

Comment: "Unpacked into a file" - what does that mean!?!  Please follow the instructions in the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: I got everything figured out as far as setup except for during the project setup settings it asks for settings based on how it was built (see included picture).

Comment: Oh, not enough reputation for a picture. settings such as "use wxwidgets DLL" and "wxWidgets is built as a monolithic library". What should I check?

Comment: Got bored trying to do it your way and just fixed the initial issue. Topic closed